# Google charts vAxis

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

[image]

I build graphics and display in one place using Combo Chart google in the object vAxis I set the color and name for each chart:

```
vAxes: {
    0: {
        title:'График 1',
        textStyle: {color: '#21C40A'},
        minorGridlines: {count: 2, color: '#ccc'},
        titleTextStyle: {color: '#21C40A'},
    },
    1: {
        title:'График 2',
        textStyle: {color: '#E89712'},
        minorGridlines: {count: 2, color: '#ccc'},
        titleTextStyle: {color: '#E89712'}
    },
    2: {
        title:'График 3',
        textStyle: {color: '#390983'},
        minorGridlines: {count: 2, color: '#ccc'},
        titleTextStyle: {color: '#390983'}
    }
}
```

The question is how you can specify the position of the y coordinate or take the distance from each other so that the data does not stack on each other?
Can I get it this way?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on one of the right side axis,
set --> `textPosition: 'in'`

this will move one inside the chart, otherwise,
they will always stack on top of each other...

see following working snippet,
also use `chartArea.right` to allow enough room for the labels and titles...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Month');
    data.addColumn('number', "Average Temperature");
    data.addColumn('number', "Average Hours of Daylight");
    data.addColumn('number', "Average 1");
    data.addColumn('number',"Average 2")
    data.addRows([
      [new Date(2014, 0),  -.5,  8.7,7,11],
      [new Date(2014, 1),   .4,  8.7,5,12],
      [new Date(2014, 2),   .5,   12,6,13],
      [new Date(2014, 3),  2.9, 15.7,5,14],
      [new Date(2014, 4),  6.3, 18.6,8,15],
      [new Date(2014, 5),    9, 20.9,8,16],
      [new Date(2014, 6), 10.6, 19.8,9,16],
      [new Date(2014, 7), 10.3, 16.6,7,15],
      [new Date(2014, 8),  7.4, 13.3,8,14],
      [new Date(2014, 9),  4.4,  9.9,12,13],
      [new Date(2014, 10), 1.1,  6.6,11,12],
      [new Date(2014, 11), -.2,  4.5,11,11]
    ]);

    var classicOptions = {
      title: 'Average Temperatures and Daylight in Iceland Throughout the Year',
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      chartArea: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        top: 72,
        left: 60,
        bottom: 48,
        right: 84
      },
      series: {
        0: {targetAxisIndex: 0},
        1: {targetAxisIndex: 1},
        2: {targetAxisIndex: 2}
      },
      vAxes: {
        0: {
          textPosition: 'out',
          title: 'Temps (Celsius)'
        },
        1: {
          textPosition: 'out',
          title: 'Daylight',
          viewWindow: {
            max: 30
          }
        },
        2: {
          textPosition: 'in',
          title: 'third',
          viewWindow: {
            max: 40
          }
        }
      },
      hAxis: {
        ticks: [
          new Date(2014, 0), new Date(2014, 1), new Date(2014, 2), new Date(2014, 3),
          new Date(2014, 4),  new Date(2014, 5), new Date(2014, 6), new Date(2014, 7),
          new Date(2014, 8), new Date(2014, 9), new Date(2014, 10), new Date(2014, 11)
        ]
      },
    };

    var classicChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    classicChart.draw(data, classicOptions);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```css
html, body, div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry! Updated question

Comment: don't believe that is possible via standard config options -- first thought would be to use multiple charts beside each other, only show axis on first two

Comment: This would all be much easier if they gave you explicit control over the `textPosition` other than 'in', 'out', 'none'. Ie. a, left/right pixel position that could let you stack an arbitrary amount of axes.