# Google Charts: Scaling each series in line chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a line chart with multiple series on it:

- X axis is time
- Y axis has speed and vehicle RPM

Speed is in the range -20 to 130 while RPM is in the range 0 to 8000. I'd like to have both of these series scaled separately, so that I can clearly see the trends of both. [image: speed,rpm vs time]

My draw function looks something like this:

```
var do_chart = function (readings) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
    var fields_using = $('#select-y').val(); 
    // fields are selected from a select dropdown
    _.forEach(fields_using, function(v) {
        data.addColumn('number', v);
    });
    _.forEach(readings, function (v) {
        var row = [new Date(v.timestamp)];
        _.forEach(fields_using, function(f) {
            row.push(v[f]);
        });
        data.addRow(row);
    });
    var options = {
        title: 'Speed vs. Time',
        curveType: 'function',
        animation:{
            duration: 100,
            startup: true
        },
        explorer: {
            actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
            axis: 'horizontal',
            keepInBounds: true,
            maxZoomIn: 0
        },
        legend: {position: 'bottom'}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is have dual y-axes. You can look at the [Google Charts documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#dual-y-charts) where it talks about it. This way you can preserve the values, as you won't need to scale them.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it, pity having 3+ `vAxes` looks horrible.

Comment: when `vAxes` = 3, try using `textPosition: 'in'` on one of the right side axis, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45918185/5090771)...

Comment: If you want to align gridlines, even though different axes use different values for the same gridlines, that can be tricky.  Experiment with the viewWindow option, and maybe specify 'ticks' options as well.